# c#: Programatically call a TableAdapters.Fill Method using a string to Specify the TableAdapter

Tags: c#, ado.net

Greetings Guru's

I have a peculiar problem with TableAdapters and the Fill Method.
I have a bunch of autogenerated TableAdapters as a result of binding an app to a DataSource.
They are bound to controls on my form and work as expected.

Now I need to call the fill method on the TableAdapters from time to time
and I want to do It programatically (TableAdapters["Name"].Fill(myDataSet["Name_Table"]);)
instead of literally (TableAdapter_Name.Fill(myDataSet.Name_Table);

The Idea is to pass a string to a method that can call the targeted TableAdapter by parsing the string to recognize the desired object.
I've often wished that C# supported creating dynamic statements/methods (from strings) that can be executed like a regular statement.

Is this possible? (If not it seems like I'll be doing a LOT of literal typing to represent all of my TableAdapters and when I do a lot of literal typing of strings in my code it's a RED FLAG that I'm doing something wrong"

Help, Zion

NameTableAdapter.Fill(myDataSet.Name);
StateTableAdapter.Fill(myDataSet.State);
CityTableAdapter.Fill(myDataSet.City);

Answer (score 0):

You might create a Dictionary<DataTable, TableAdapterWrapper> that associates your datatables with their table adapters. The wrapper class can use reflection to call the Fill method (since, if I'm not mistaken, the table adapters don't implement a common interface or inherit from a common base class).

```
public class TableAdapterWrapper
{
    object tableAdapter;
    DataTable table;

    public TableAdapterWrapper(object tableAdapter, DataTable table)
    {
        this.tableAdapter = tableAdapter;
        this.table = table;
    }

    public void Fill()
    {
        var methodInfo = tableAdapter.GetType().GetMethod("Fill");
        methodInfo.Invoke(tableAdapter, new object[] { table });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using names you can use enums to index array of Adapters like the following

```
enum Types
{
Adapter1,Adapter2
}
SqlDataAdapter [] Adapters = new SqlDataAdapter();
adapters[Types.Adpter1] = adapter1;
adapters[Types.Adpter1] = adapter2;

//call
Adapters[Types.Adpter1].Fill(table);
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look @ [CS-Script](http://www.csscript.net/) this is free library for scripting with c# syntax .using this library you can write a method which will get a string and run it as statement .
this is the solution I use for creating dynamic statements .

Comment: This is COOL!, I did not know this existed, I've been an autoIT and VBSCRIPT guy for years and wanted more PowER! (PowerShell is clunky slow, F# is inmature) This is what I've been looking for. Thanks for that tip. Wheel are turning now. WoW!

Comment: it is really powerful and easy to use ,happy that your problem is solved .
BTW if you liked it or it solved your problem you can mar it as your answer or vote to it .thanks

Comment: I have not had an oppurtunity to implement the solutions offered as yet. CS-Script won't be beacause it's a deployable app.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you are asking for something like the javascript `eval(...)` statement.  No, C# doesn't have that, and for good reason.  Among other things, it would have to fire up a new compiler for every instance of this at runtime.  There may be some libraries or external tools that provide this type of functionality, but I would be very wary of using them for something like this.

If these TableAdapters are on a form, then they are instance members and you could use the `Type.GetField` method to find the adapter and then the `Type.GetMethod` to find the `Fill` method on the TableAdapter to invoke.

But my question is, **why** do you need to do this?  To me, the red flag is the fact that somebody is trying to create such a messy abstraction over a data layer.  Things to consider:

- Most databases have very few tables that are small enough to dump all rows from without killing both database and app performance.  You should almost never use the parameterless `Fill`/`GetData` methods.
- Using Reflection means you don't get any compile-time checking, and unless it's very tightly controlled (i.e. as part of some DI framework), it's likely to lead to mysterious, hard-to-debug errors down the road.
- The `Fill` method itself takes a typed parameter, so if you try to write a "generic" fill method, it makes it possible for someone to write code that passes an incorrect table type, which could lead to all sorts of fun and unpredictable problems.
- TableAdapters in general are - how should I say this - not exactly deprecated, but not the preferred means of data access today.  Entity Framework and Linq to SQL are much more attractive options.  Unless you've inherited this DAL from a previous designer, why use it at all?

I think you should explain more about your problem domain.  I am willing to bet that there is a better design available for your particular requirements.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback bro. Thanks